# Hibernate 6 does not support datepart func with weekday

Tags: hibernate

During a migration on hibernate from version 5 to version 6, i saw that hibernate is registering functions in a different way with the dialects from version 6.

i have a problem with the datepart function, which should receive 'weekday' as his first parameter.

today, i see that weekday is not part of the TemporalUnit enum, that is the type of the first argument of the datepart function.

here is an example of a query that worked for me at the previous version, but no longer in the new one:

```
SELECT b FROM Book b  WHERE datepart(weekday, b.publicationDate) = 1
```

its important to say that other time-untis (like year, month, day, minute etc) are working fine, also in the new version.

there is an alternative, or something else i should use?

Comment: A relevant thread of discussion about a relevant problem [with-hours](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hibernate-6-criteria-hour-is-not-a-recognized-built-in-function-name/8738/2)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue on a project that has Hibernate baked in very deep. In a new project, I would never ever choose Hibernate. We spend more time working around the darn thing than actually saving time using it... Anyway here's my workaround:

https://www.almanac.com/how-find-day-week

```
public class CustomSQLServerDialect extends SQLServerDialect {

@Override
public void initializeFunctionRegistry(FunctionContributions functionContributions) {
    super.initializeFunctionRegistry(functionContributions);
    
    BasicTypeRegistry basicTypeRegistry = functionContributions.getTypeConfiguration().getBasicTypeRegistry();        
    functionContributions.getFunctionRegistry().patternDescriptorBuilder("weekday", 
        "coalesce(nullif((" +
                    // YY as int
                    "cast(substring(convert(char(10), ?1, 126), 3, 2) as int) + " +
                    // 0.25 * YY as int (truncated)
                    "cast(cast(substring(convert(char(10), ?1, 126), 3, 2) as int) * 0.25 as int) + " +
                    // dd as int
                    "cast(substring(convert(char(10), ?1, 126), 9, 2) as int) + " +
                    // month key
                    "case month(?1) " +
                    // 1 (or 0 if leap year)
                    "when 1 then case when case when (datepart(year, ?1) % 4 = 0 and datepart(year, ?1) % 100 <> 0) or datepart(year, ?1) % 400 = 0 then 1 else 0 end = 1 then 0 else 1 end  " +
                    // 4 (or 3 if leap year)
                    "when 2 then case when case when (datepart(year, ?1) % 4 = 0 and datepart(year, ?1) % 100 <> 0) or datepart(year, ?1) % 400 = 0 then 1 else 0 end = 1 then 3 else 4 end  " +
                    "when 3 then 4 " +
                    "when 4 then 0 " +
                    "when 5 then 2 " +
                    "when 6 then 5 " +
                    "when 7 then 0 " +
                    "when 8 then 3 " +
                    "when 9 then 6 " +
                    "when 10 then 1 " +
                    "when 11 then 4 " +
                    "when 12 then 6 " +
                    "else 0 " +
                    "end " +
                    // subtract 1 if year between 2000 and 2099
                    "- (case when datepart(year, ?1) between 2000 and 2099 then 1 else 0 end) " +
            ") % 7, 0), 6)") // if no remainder, it is 6 (saturday)
        .setExactArgumentCount(1)
        .setParameterTypes(TEMPORAL)
        .setInvariantType(basicTypeRegistry.resolve(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER))
        .register();
    
}
```

And then register it in your application.properties or yml file or whatever file you are using to configure Hibernate. Eg, for Spring, spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=com.my.hibernate.dialect.CustomSQLServerDialect

It would be a heck of a lot faster though to just split that datepart out into a computed column and index it. Then you can just query directly on an int column instead of messing about with all this.

Comment: yes, this what i am working on right now, to override SqlServerDielct and register those functions my way. thank you for your informatic answer.